# I am not able to make my app scrollble, despite of having SingleChildScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

In my app, i have used `BlogTile` and `CategoryTile` widgets (which were made by myself) and I am using them in `Contaniers/Columns`. When I used `SingleChildScrollView` with `CategoryTile`, and made axis as horizontal, it was working fine. But as soon as i use it for `BlogTile`, it doen't work. I am not able to scroll in my app vertically. But when i try to scroll vertically by clicking on the part between `CategoryTile` and `BlogTile`, it works. But when i try to scroll by clicking from anyb other section of it, it doesn't work. Please someone help me

Check this code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_app/helper/data.dart';
import 'package:news_app/helper/news.dart';
import 'package:news_app/models/article_model.dart';
import 'package:news_app/models/category_models.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<CategoryModel> categories = new List<CategoryModel>();
  List<ArticleModel> articles = new List<ArticleModel>();
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    categories = getCategories();
    getNews();
  }

  getNews() async {
    News newsClass = News();
    await newsClass.getNews();
    articles = newsClass.news;
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
      print('Done');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Flutter',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'News',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //elevation: 2.0,
        ),
        body: loading
            ? Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              )
            : SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ///Categories
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                            height: 70.0,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: categories.length,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return CategoryTile(
                                  imageUrl: categories[index].imageUrl,
                                  categoryName: categories[index].categoryName,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
                          ///Blogs
                          SingleChildScrollView(

                            child: Container(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: articles.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return BlogTile(
                                    imageUrl: articles[index].urlToImage,
                                    title: articles[index].title,
                                    desc: articles[index].description,
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final imageUrl, categoryName;
  CategoryTile({this.imageUrl, this.categoryName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
              child: Image.network(
                imageUrl,
                width: 120.0,
                height: 160.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 120.0,
              height: 160.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
              child: Text(
                categoryName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BlogTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl, title, desc;
  BlogTile(
      {@required this.imageUrl, @required this.desc, @required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(imageUrl),
          Text(title),
          Text(desc),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are `SingleScrollChildView` widgets a lot.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα yeah i know, but when i started writing my code, i only used it once. But when it was not working, i started using it in different places, an ended up using it literally at every possible place to make it work out.

Comment: If your app is about NewsAPI, I have a project by using GetX, if you are interested the source code is [here](https://github.com/warcayac/NewsApiFlutterWithGetX).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you're giving unbounded height and width to some of the ScrollViews.
First off, don't use multiple scrolling widgets nested inside one another. But if you want to do that, try wrapping each of your scrollview within a Container like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 child: Container(
   height: 50.0,
   width: 50.0,
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: ...,
   ),
 ),
),
```

What I'd also suggest is that instead of using a SingleChildScrollView, use a ListView widget. It works almost the same and you can put multiple children inside it. A simple ListView() will work. Don't use ListView.builder or any other aggregate function.

Comment: Actually, there was only one at the starting, but after i came to know that it wasn't working, i started putting more and more of them to make it work.

Comment: Okay. Did you try the solution? Do let me know if it works or not.